# How to display .svg image using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a .svg image file I want to display in my project.

I tried using UIImageView, which works for the .png & .jpg image formats, but not for the .svg extension. Is there any way to display a .svg image using UIWebView or UIImageView ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149785/xcode-6-allows-vector-image-assets-any-idea-how-to-use-them and http://yberdnikov.github.io/2014/06/18/uiwebview-and-svg-images-scaling/

Comment: https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit This has a very similar API as `UIImageView`

Comment: alternatively you may convert svg to jpg or png and use that image... instead of wasting time to search for svg support.

Comment: Is there any code available in swift to convert .svg image into jpg?

Comment: You can also try Snowflake https://github.com/onmyway133/snowflake

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this code

```
var path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("nameOfFile", ofType: "svg")!

        var url: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)  //Creating a URL which points towards our path

       //Creating a page request which will load our URL (Which points to our path)
        var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
       webView.loadRequest(request)  //Telling our webView to load our above request
```

Comment: what exactly is webview here?
And it gives me this fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: webview is obviously UIWebView.

Comment: Ankit Vij, if it unwraps a nil, it possibly means the path is wrong and couldn't find the file.

Comment: @SmallChess UIWebView is obviously deprecated.

Comment: It's a good and simple solution. However the webView var could be specified somewhere in the code. Just to make the example a little bit better. Also a better indentation would make my brain happier to read it.

Comment: How can i use in ImageView ?

Answer (score 24):

There is no Inbuilt support for SVG in Swift.
So we need to use other libraries.

The simple SVG libraries in swift are :

**1) [SwiftSVG](https://github.com/mchoe/SwiftSVG) Library**

It gives you more option to Import as UIView, CAShapeLayer, Path, etc

To modify your SVG Color and Import as UIImage you can use my extension codes for the library mentioned in below link,

Click here to know on using [SwiftSVG](https://github.com/mchoe/SwiftSVG) library :
[Using SwiftSVG to set SVG for Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45724864/5078763)

|OR|

**2) [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) Library**

2.1) Use pod to install :

```
pod 'SVGKit', :git => 'https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit.git', :branch => '2.x'
```

2.2) Add framework

> Goto AppSettings
>   -> General Tab
>   -> Scroll down to Linked Frameworks and Libraries
>   -> Click on plus icon
>   -> Select SVG.framework

2.3) Add in Objective-C to Swift bridge file bridging-header.h :

```
#import <SVGKit/SVGKit.h>
#import <SVGKit/SVGKImage.h>
```

2.4) Create SvgImg Folder (for better organization) in Project and add SVG files inside it.

> Note : Adding Inside Assets Folder won't work and SVGKit searches for file only in Project folders

2.5) Use in your Swift Code as below :

```
import SVGKit
```

and

```
let namSvgImgVar: SVGKImage = SVGKImage(named: "NamSvgImj")
```

> Note : SVGKit Automatically apends extention ".svg" to the string you specify

```
let namSvgImgVyuVar = SVGKImageView(SVGKImage: namSvgImgVar)

let namImjVar: UIImage = namSvgImgVar.UIImage
```

There are many more options for you to init SVGKImage and SVGKImageView

There are also other classes u can explore

```
    SVGRect
    SVGCurve
    SVGPoint
    SVGAngle
    SVGColor
    SVGLength

    and etc ...
```

Comment: Good explanation. But you should/can not use `SVGKImageView` directly. Instead `SVGKFastImageView`or `SVGKLayeredImageView` must be used.

Comment: Add `SVGKit.framework` in Linked Frameworks and Libraries

Answer (score 21):

My solution to show .svg in UIImageView from URL.
You need to install [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) pod

Then just use it like this:

```
import SVGKit

 let svg = URL(string: "https://openclipart.org/download/181651/manhammock.svg")!
 let data = try? Data(contentsOf: svg)
 let receivedimage: SVGKImage = SVGKImage(data: data)
 imageview.image = receivedimage.uiImage
```

or you can use extension for async download

```
extension UIImageView {
func downloadedsvg(from url: URL, contentMode mode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
    contentMode = mode
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard
            let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
            let data = data, error == nil,
            let receivedicon: SVGKImage = SVGKImage(data: data),
            let image = receivedicon.uiImage
            else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.image = image
        }
    }.resume()
}
}
```

How to use:

```
let svg = URL(string: "https://openclipart.org/download/181651/manhammock.svg")!

imageview.downloadedsvg(from: svg)
```

Answer (score 21):

SVG file support is added to Xcode 12.

[image]

Comment: Any idea how this works ? I tried adding an SVG file to an .xcassets file, and it just gave an error.

Comment: Which Xcode are you using? It worked for me in .xcassets

Comment: Can be use for xcode 12 as well, they provided backward compatibility.

Comment: But that doesn't work for uploaded images in running app because assets are not writeable.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) for example.

1) Integrate it according to instructions. Drag&dropping the .framework file is fast and easy.

2) Make sure you have an Objective-C to Swift bridge file bridging-header.h with import code in it:

```
#import <SVGKit/SVGKit.h>
#import <SVGKit/SVGKImage.h>
```

3) Use the framework like this, assuming that dataFromInternet is NSData, previously downloaded from network:

```
let anSVGImage: SVGKImage = SVGKImage(data: dataFromInternet)
myIUImageView.image = anSVGImage.UIImage
```

The framework also allows to init an SVGKImage from other different sources, for example it can download image for you when you provide it with URL. But in my case it was crashing in case of unreachable url, so it turned out to be better to manage networking by myself. More info on it [here](http://t-machine.org/index.php/2013/01/02/svgkit-2013-recipes/).

Comment: thanks... I have already tried this too. Its an easy way to download & display .svg image

Comment: thanks for the link to the framework. works perfect for me

Comment: very very slow framework. Takes 25 seconds to display a local svg of size 1M

Answer (score 17):

You can add **New Symbol Image Set** in .xcassets, then you can add SVG file in it

and use it same like image.

[image]

**Note: This doesn't work on all SVG. You can have a look at the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/creating_custom_symbol_images_for_your_app)**

Comment: This will only work with a very specific subset of SVG files, cf. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/creating_custom_symbol_images_for_your_app

Comment: Thanks @DirtyHenry I have added in a note in answer.

Answer (score 11):

#### Swift 3.0 version :

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "svgNameFileHere", ofType: "svg")!
if path != "" {
    let fileURL:URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let req = URLRequest(url: fileURL)
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = false
    self.webView.loadRequest(req)
}
else {
   //handle here if path not found
}
```

**Third party libraries**

https://github.com/exyte/Macaw

https://github.com/mchoe/SwiftSVG

**UIWebView and WKWebView booster to load faster**

https://github.com/bernikovich/WebViewWarmUper

Comment: webView is the only way to open the .SVG files , i want to load multiple SVG files in a scroll view .

Comment: create html text at runtime or use tableview with webview

Comment: How to use in ImageView ?

Comment: @KrutarthPatel you can use third party library in UIView

Comment: @PareshNavadiya UIWebView takes 1 second delay to load

Comment: @KrutarthPatel Need to check my answer again for UIWebView and WKWebView booster to load faster

Answer (score 9):

In case you want to use a `WKWebView` to load a .svg image that is coming from a `URLRequest`, you can simply achieve it like this:

**Swift 4**

```
if let request = URLRequest(url: urlString), let svgString = try? String(contentsOf: request) {
  wkWebView.loadHTMLString(svgString, baseURL: request)
}
```

It's much simpler than the other ways of doing it, and you can also persist your .svg string somewhere to load it later, even offline if you need to.

Comment: A nice and very clean solution.

Comment: How do i get the scale to be centred and fill the frame, instead of the scroll view it adds?

Comment: I believe you can only achieve this by injecting Javascript code inside the WKWebView, or changing the configuration after the svg has loaded at some WKNavigationDelegate method.

Comment: The Swift compiler would not accept String(contentsOf: request) for me, Instead of a request it wants an URL. For baseURL, it also wants an url, not a request.

Answer (score 7):

You can keep your images as strings and use WKWebView to display them:

```
let webView: WKWebView = {
    let mySVGImage = "<svg height=\"190\"><polygon points=\"100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180\" style=\"fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;\"></svg>"
    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = false
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.preferences = preferences
    let wv = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
    wv.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    wv.loadHTMLString(mySVGImage, baseURL: nil)
    return wv
}()
```

Comment: Thanks! You made me understand how it works. Now I just need to figure out how to save a .svg string that comes from a POST Request.

Comment: Do you have a repo example of this in use?

Comment: Have tried https://gist.github.com/lfcj/a08a84eb0fc20f92849dbb49e6dfa435, but it does not work :( Did this work for you, @nanvel?

Comment: The SVG has error - polygon doesn't have closing tag slash

Answer (score 7):

Since XCode 12, it is possible to add SVG assets to your project.

To add svg file to your project:

1. Drag and drop your svg file into the assets catalog.
2. Selected the newly added asset.
3. Your svg image will be added as 1x. Select it and change the `Scales` property to `Single Scale` in attributes inspector.

[image]

Comment: You also need to check preserve vector data

Comment: Additionally, sometimes you want to tint the color of the image, e.g. icon, you can change "render as" template image.

Answer (score 5):

[SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) helped me on getting the image from URL.

First, add `pod 'SVGKit'` in your Podfile.

Second, `import SVGKit` into your class.

Third, create an object of SVGImage.

```
let mySVGImage: SVGKImage = SVGKImage(contentsOf: URL(string: path))
```

Finally, add this image to your UIImageView.

```
yourImageView.image = mySVGImage.uiImage
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple class that can display SVG images in a `UIView`

```
import UIKit

public class SVGImageView: UIView {
    private let webView = UIWebView()

    public init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        webView.backgroundColor = .clear
        addSubview(webView)
        webView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalTo(self)
        }
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    deinit {
        webView.stopLoading()
    }

    public func load(url: String) {
        webView.stopLoading()
        if let url = URL(string: fullUrl) {
            webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }
}

extension SVGImageView: UIWebViewDelegate {
    public func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        let scaleFactor = webView.bounds.size.width / webView.scrollView.contentSize.width
        if scaleFactor <= 0 {
            return
        }

        webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scaleFactor
        webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = scaleFactor
        webView.scrollView.zoomScale = scaleFactor
    }
}
```

Comment: did any one try this ?

Comment: @cybergeeeek I did an almost identical solution in Objective-C before, so this should work. The only downside is the slow loading time of the web view, so the images will appear a half a second after the screen is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

To render SVG file you can use [Macaw](http://github.com/exyte/macaw). Also Macaw supports transformations, user events, animation and various effects.

You can render SVG file with zero lines of code. For more info please check this article: [Render SVG file with Macaw](https://github.com/exyte/Macaw/wiki/Render-SVG-file).

**DISCLAIMER:** I am affiliated with this project.

Comment: Can I ask you to please read [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085) This is clearly your own project, do disclose this in your posts.

Comment: I gave Macaw just a try but quality of SVG ist too worse

Answer (score 2):

As I know there are 2 different graphic formats:

1. Raster graphics (uses bitmaps) and is used  in JPEG, PNG, APNG, GIF, and MPEG4 file format.
2. Vector graphics  (uses points, lines, curves and other shapes). Vector graphics are used  in the SVG, EPS, PDF or AI graphic file formats.

So if you need to use an image stored in SVG File in your Xcode I would suggest:

1. Convert SVG file to PDF.  I used  https://document.online-convert.com/convert/svg-to-pdf
2. Use Xcode to manage you PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

UIImage doesn't load the SVG with iOS17 natively.

macOS:
As of macOS 14.0 (Sonoma) the NSImage has native support for SVG images loading using Data or URL. Earlier macOS SDKs contain `_NSSVGImageRep` (down to Catalina 10.15) but 14.0 is the first release that has this class registered (`NSImageRep.registeredClasses`). However, the support for masks and CSS classes is still limited (10NOV2023).

Please note this is not documented and official. The representation is a private class `_NSSVGImageRep` and you need CGImage to get bitmap data. Doesn't work with iOS16/iOS17.

```
let xmlSVGImage = "<svg width=\"195\" height=\"190\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><polygon points=\"100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180\" style=\"fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;\" /></svg>"
let svgData = xmlSVGImage.data(using: .utf8)!
let svgImage = NSImage(data: svgData)
print(svgImage)

Optional(<NSImage 0x600001400140 Size={185, 190} RepProvider=<NSImageArrayRepProvider: 0x600002704220, reps:(
    "_NSSVGImageRep 0x60000063c1e0 Size={185, 190} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=0x0 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=(null)"
)>>)
```

To get scaled bitmap image:

```
    var rect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1432, height: 1380)
    let scaledCGImage  = svgImage?.cgImage(forProposedRect: &rect, context: nil, hints: nil)
    print(scaledCGImage)

Optional(<CGImage 0x124e058e0> (DP)
    <<CGColorSpace 0x600000a512c0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; Color LCD)>
        width = 2864, height = 2760, bpc = 16, bpp = 64, row bytes = 22912 
        kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGImageByteOrder16Little  | kCGImagePixelFormatPacked | kCGBitmapFloatComponents 
        is mask? No, has masking color? No, has soft mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? Yes)
```

Mind that secure archiving doesn't work. It will unarchive as bitmap.

```
let archivedData = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: svgImage!, requiringSecureCoding: true)
let unarchivedImage = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSImage.self, from: archivedData) as! NSImage

<NSImage 0x600003d04960 Size={185, 190} RepProvider=<NSImageArrayRepProvider: 0x600000e085b0, reps:(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x6000027050a0 Size={185, 190} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=185x190 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600000c2a400",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x600002705880 Size={185, 190} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=370x380 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600000c2a580",
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x6000027057a0 Size={185, 190} ColorSpace=(not yet loaded) BPS=8 BPP=(not yet loaded) Pixels=555x570 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=(not yet loaded) CurrentBacking=nil (faulting) CGImageSource=0x600000c2a880"
)>>
```

If you disable secure archiving/unarchiving you can get original SVGImageRep

```
let unsecureArchivedData = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: svgImage!, requiringSecureCoding: false)
let unsecureUnArchiver = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: unsecureArchivedData)
unsecureUnArchiver.requiresSecureCoding = false
let decodedRoot = unsecureUnArchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "root") as? NSImage

Optional(<NSImage 0x600001094000 Size={185, 170} RepProvider=<NSImageArrayRepProvider: 0x6000023900d0, reps:(
    "_NSSVGImageRep 0x600000294820 Size={185, 170} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=0 Pixels=0x0 Alpha=NO AppearanceName=(null)"
)>>)
```

It's even possible to get SVG string using `NSKeyedArchiver` + `NSKeyedUnarchiver` delegate method `unarchiver:didDecodeObject:`. Look for NSMutableData

Even though _NSSVGImageRep is present in 10.15 etc, it is not in registered classes. It has started to be registered on Sonoma

```
let registeredClasses = NSImageRep.registeredClasses
print(registeredClasses)

[NSBitmapImageRep, NSPICTImageRep, NSPDFImageRep, _NSSVGImageRep, NSEPSImageRep]
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pod called '**SVGParser**'. https://cocoapods.org/pods/SVGParser.

After adding it in your pod file, all you have to do is to import this module to the class that you want to use it. You should show the SVG image in an ImageView.

There are three cases you can show this SVGimage:

1. Load SVG from local path as Data
2. Load SVG from local path
3. Load SVG from remote URL

You can also find an example project in GitHub: https://github.com/AndreyMomot/SVGParser.
Just download the project and run it to see how it works.

Comment: This library used UIWebView which is deprecated on iOS 12...

Answer (score 0):

Here is objective c solution

```
- (void)loadSVG:(NSString *)url {
if (url.length == 0) return;
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                            completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpURLResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    if (error == nil && [response.MIMEType hasPrefix:@"image"] && httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200)
    {
        SVGKImage *receivedIcon = [SVGKImage imageWithData:data];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            imageView.image = receivedIcon.UIImage;
        });
        
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error %@ ", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}] resume];
```

}