# How to use SVG image file with UIImageView swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8.2

i've created this code with gives me an image, but i don want to use a png or jpg file. I want to know how to use a similar code but with SVG image file

```
let iconImageView: UIImageView = {
  let imageView = UIImageView()
  imageView.image = imagem
  return imageView
}()
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691839/how-to-display-svg-image-using-swift

Comment: yeah I already saw this, but not work for me =(