# How to add flag image from an API?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

```
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var alpha3CodeLbl: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var regionLbl: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var flagImage: UIImageView!

    var countrie:jsonStruct?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        alpha3CodeLbl.text = countrie?.alpha3Code
        regionLbl.text = countrie?.region
        let urlString = "http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all" + (countrie?.flag)!

        flagImage.downloadedFrom(url: url!)


    }
}

extension UIImageView {
    func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.image = image
            }
            }.resume()
    }
    func downloadedFrom(link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloadedFrom(url: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the flag  image form this API http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

There is no error but the image does not appear. But there is no result if there anyone here can fix this issue.
Please, not that everything is okay and try to get the image in too many ways but still no result.

Also, I try this

```
    let urlString = "http[enter image description
 here][1]://restcountries.eu" + (countrie?.flag)!
```

Comment: Send URL example because   `let data = data`  not image in this  `http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`

Comment: Send Example from this url  `let urlString = "http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all" + (countrie?.flag)!`  what is  (countrie?.flag)

Comment: That API has no support for the URL you are trying to use. The flag URLs are in the form `https://restcountries.eu/data/jor.svg`. And `UIImage` doesn't work with SVG files.

Comment: countrie:jsonStruct this is a struct contain var fla type of string

Comment: the problem with svg

Comment: thank you all i'll start work on this by using  SVGKit

Comment: i fixed this issue by using webView and display the link in it :) 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to fix.   You should test the url before using it.

```
let str = "yourURL"
guard let theUrl = URL(string: str) else { return }
```

As mentioned by @rmaddy in a comment above, UIImage isn't going to work with SVG files. Use a UIWebView instead

```
var request = URLRequest(url:theUrl)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Or try SVGKit to convert SVG as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38152144/1293726)

Comment: my code are working will, when change the api it's working and there is no problem
my problem how to make  the image appear  in my imageView from this api 
while the image from this api 
https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats apear on my imageView

Comment: PNG and SVG are two different formats and you must adapt your code. Converting SVG is probably what you will want to do. I updated my post with a link to instructions for converting SVG.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have explained to me many meanings and opened meanings that I did not know and made me pay attention to new things

Comment: absolutely  but FYI 
i displayed the picture in webkit view without using pods or any 
and   i know that by you telling me there is SVG image 
thank you