# Load an svg from remote resource in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am using a REST API (https://restcountries.eu/) and want to download the flag image (which is an .svg) and show it as a `UIImage`. I tried the standard way with:

```
    func requestData(at url: URL, success: @escaping (_ data: Data) -> Void, failure: ((_ error: NetworkError) -> Void)? = nil) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (responseData, response, responseError) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if responseError != nil {
                failure?(.failedRequest)
            } else if let data = responseData {
                success(data)
            } else {
                failure?(.corruptedData)
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

and the data downloads fine, but when I try to show the image with `UIImage(data: data)`, the image is `nil`. Am I missing something?

Comment: iOS lacks native support for SVG, but there are other work arounds to make it work.

Comment: For SVG guidance, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691839/how-to-display-svg-image-using-swift

Comment: `UIImage` does not support SVG. Find flags in PNG or JPG format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display .svg image using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691839/how-to-display-svg-image-using-swift)