# How to load .SVG image URL into image view in ios application using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, svg

i want to make an image with transparent background which is capture by me and there should be only edges of image.

Then after i want to change color of that image's edges.

so suggest me is there any way to do this.

thanks

**UPDATE**

My question is not duplicate because the difference is:

1. i want load svg url only into imageView not into webView
2. there should be change tint color of svg image which loaded into image view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display .svg image using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691839/how-to-display-svg-image-using-swift)

Answer (score 1):

Use this to upload the image from the url

```
func download(url:String) {

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];

    let filePath="\(documentsPath)/img.svg"

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        if let url = URL(string: "\(url)/img.svg"),

            let urlData = NSData(contentsOf: url) {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                urlData.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true)

                print("done")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to use

```
download(url: "https://yuordomin.com/nameimge.svg")
```

Comment: i don't want to upload but i am getting svg url from api response and that url i want to show into image view .

Comment: Sorry I can not serve you

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** My answer ignores the aspect that you explicitly want `SVG` images, sorry for that; still, you could convert your images to `PDF` and use the described approach.

---

You can use use the `renderingMode` property of `UIImage` to generate a template image which supports setting a tint color. This will interpret all non-transparent pixels as the "foreground" which will get colored by the tint.

There are two ways to do so:

1. Set the image's render mode in the asset catalog by opening the Attributes Inspector and setting the dropdown `Render as` to `Template Image`. When you load this image with `UIImage(named:)` you automatically get it as a template image.
2. When you already have the `UIImage` instance you can convert it to a template image: `let templateImage = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)`

In both cases you can set the tint color of the image with `templateImage.tintColor = yourColor`.

Comment: here i am getting .svg url into api response and that .svg url show directly into my image view . is it possible to show in image view directly? thanks