# SwiftSVG doesn't display image

Tags: swift, svg, swiftsvg

I'm working on a project which uses SVG-images and I have read that handling sag images isn't that easy with iOS.
What I have already tried was this answer: [How to display .svg image using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691839/how-to-display-svg-image-using-swift). 
Where I changed the deprecated UIWebKit to WKWebKit, but unfortunately I get an error (nil) when it tries to unwrap the image.
Therefore I tried the second answer with the SwiftSVG-Framework.

After I installed the Framework I tried to make it work. The code compiles and has no errors but the image I use doesn't get displayed. 
The code I used was as follows:

```
let fistBump = UIView(SVGNamed: "ukulele")     // In the main bundle
self.addSubview(fistBump)
```

Does somebody know how to handle svg images in swift or is there a way to make SwiftSVG work?

**Edit**

I have tried to add a frame an constraints to my view but unfortunately this didn't fix the problem. There are still no errors shown and the picture isn't displayed.
The code I used looks like this:

```
let fistBump = UIView(SVGNamed: "ukulele")     // In the main bundle
self.addSubview(fistBump)
fistBump.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 50, height: 50) 
self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": fistBump]))
self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": fistBump]))
```

What I have also discovered is that no matter what I type into the SVGNamed-String I never get an Error so basically this works but the image is obviously not displayed:

```
let fistBump = UIView(SVGNamed: "test321")     // Doesn't throw an error
self.addSubview(fistBump)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a frame/constraints

```
let fistBump = UIView(SVGNamed: "ukulele") 
fistBump.frame = ////
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried it to set a frame but unfortunately that didn't work. See my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can try add the svg view as a subview of another view which you can set the constraint

Comment: Can you expand on this by adding an example?