# Creating a vector UIImage from a remote URL

Tags: swift, uiimage, uikit

Since you can create vector image assets in Xcode with PDFs and SVGs, is it possible to download a PDF/SVG from a remote url (storage) and create a vector UIImage from that? I want to avoid having multiple sizes of the same picture stored, but am unsure if its possible to create a vector resource from a remote download.

`let image = UIImage(data: [*download_data*])`

Comment: Once you initialize an UIImage it is not a vector anymore.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45706892/921573 - there is no built-in support for rendering svg in iOS (except with a WebView). You would have to parse and draw the svg yourself or using a library.

Comment: A UIImage initialized from a PDF image asset marked with "Preserve Vector Data" appears to still be a vector image. Is there any other way to initialize such a UIImage?

Comment: "Once you initialize an UIImage it is not a vector anymore. "  <<<< In the asset catalogue, click "Preserve Vector Data" and it seems that UIImage can indeed be rescaled even after initializing one from a PDF vector - without losing quality.