Unable to use some SVG in iOS launch screen
Good morning,
I have a problem with using SVG image as iOS launchscreen.

UPDATE
In iOS simulator, it works on iPhone SE and iPad Pro 2nd generation, but not in iPhone 15 Pro and iPad Pro 6th generation. All simulators have iOS 17.4

These are the settings of Xcode




I also used other SVGs, always created with Illustrator and exported as SVG; but some work, some don't.
Below is the code of the two SVGs used.
BIKE (foreground.svg)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 27.8.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1024 1024;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#000000;}
</style>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M147.1,537.3c15.1-3,45.7-5.3,74.4-5.3c35.1,0,56.6,3.4,75.1,14.3c17.7,9.4,30.6,26.8,30.6,49.8
        c0,22.6-13.2,43.8-41.9,54.4v0.8c29.1,7.9,50.6,29.8,50.6,62.7c0,23-10.6,41.1-26.4,54c-18.5,14.7-49.5,23-100,23
        c-28.3,0-49.5-1.9-62.3-3.8V537.3z M204.1,634.7H223c30.2,0,46.4-12.5,46.4-31.3c0-19.3-14.7-29.4-40.8-29.4
        c-12.5,0-19.6,0.8-24.5,1.5V634.7z M204.1,747.6c5.7,0.8,12.5,0.8,22.3,0.8c26,0,49.1-9.8,49.1-36.6c0-25.7-23-35.9-51.7-35.9
        h-19.6V747.6z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M432.9,533.9v254.4h-57.8V533.9H432.9z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M482.7,533.9h57v112.5h1.1c5.7-9.8,11.7-18.9,17.4-27.9l57.8-84.6h70.6l-84.2,108.3l88.7,146.1h-67.2
        l-62.3-109.9l-21.9,26.8v83h-57V533.9z"/>
    <path class="st0" d="M865.9,680.7h-93.6v60.4h104.6v47.2H714.5V533.9h157v47.2h-99.3v52.8h93.6V680.7z"/>
</g>
</svg>

BACKGROUND (background.svg)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 27.8.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2_00000170976655646479075690000011234735479013278605_"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"
     style="enable-background:new 0 0 1024 1024;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <rect style="fill:#F3A62B;" width="1024" height="512"/>
    <rect y="512" style="fill:#329F94;" width="1024" height="512"/>
</g>
</svg>

Thank you so much.

You probably need to check the Resizing option which says - "Preserve Vector Data"

iOS does not support svg natively. It is converted to a raster image at compile time and it will probably just make your app larger. It is generally simpler to create a suitably sized png and use that.

@ShawnFrank checked but it doesn't work.

@Paulw11 with other application I don't have problem with SVG, this is the reason why I share even the SVG source code. Moreover, the image size is 540 byte, not KB

You can use an svg, but it will be converted to a raster image at build time so you may as well just create a png and be done with it.

Maybe some hints in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77356642/1619193
