# Xcode 9 asset catalog Preserves Vector Data not working?

Tags: asset-catalog, xcode9

I thought the new Preserves Vector Data checkmark in the Xcode 9 asset catalog would finally give us resizing of vector PDF images, but apparently not. Here's my test image seen at two zooms in Preview:

[image]

[image]

Nice and sharp with lots of zoom, so clearly this is a vector image. But here's what two image views look like in my app:

[image]

So where's my vector data? Is this much-desired feature *still* missing in action? Does it still work only for the automatically generated 2x and 3x images? And if so, what does the Preserve Vector Data checkbox give us that we didn't have already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works, but only if you perform the resizing yourself:

[image]

That was achieved in code, like this:

```
    let im = UIImage(named:"Image")!
    let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:self.iv2.bounds.size)
    let im2 = r.image {
        _ in
        im.draw(in: self.iv2.bounds)
    }
    self.iv2.image = im2
    self.iv2.contentMode = .center
```

So UIImageView will rasterize as it scales (e.g. for Aspect Fit), but drawing in code will preserve the vector data.

**EDIT** New in Xcode 9 beta 5, this now works as expected! In this screen shot, the second image view just does a scale-to-fill, no more. We resize sharply!

[image]

**EDIT** In playing around with Xcode 11 I have finally found a formula that always works. This means that on launch, with no extra code, in an image view or elsewhere, a vector-based image appears sharp at any size.

In the asset catalog, you must set the Scales pop-up menu to Individual Scales and put the vector-based image into the 1x slot. Check Preserve Vector Data. Done.

Comment: are you using two regular UIImageView with no code? I can't seem to have the two images to render without rasterizing with Xcode 9b6...

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis Yes! Those are just two ordinary image views, no code needed. Did you remember to check Preserves Vector Data?

Comment: yup I did check it :(. When using the snippet you provided, I get a crisp image, but with two ordinary image views, the big one gets aliased. Maybe I should file a radar with my sample project attached :/

Comment: My image views are ordinary. Do you need me to send you the example? It would be silly to submit this as a bug report now; the bug is fixed.

Comment: Sure, I'd love to have the example! Thank you! Can you send it to guillaume.algis at gmail please ?

Comment: Sent. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks Matt! It seems there's a bug with autolayout, related to the one I filled earlier today: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5005434293321728. Long story short, if the UIImageView has less than 3 "spacing"-related constraint, it will render incorrectly. Otherwise it works fine (so it worked for you because you have a top, left, and right constraints on your UIImageView). Here's the result on my machine: https://imgur.com/DpLd15i. The top image view has 2 constraints, the bottom one 3 + height. Let me know if you can reproduce it too please, thanks!

Comment: Very cool screen shot! But I have one question: Did you use the View Debugger? It sounds to me like you might have ambiguous constraints.

Comment: I didn't, but I just checked and unfortunately I have no ambiguous layout :(. It's easily reproducible by having the image view with a fixed width and height and aligned horizontally and vertically in its container.

Comment: Thanks for checking! This sounds like a really great bug report; thank you for filing it, and congratulations on some excellent research. Feel free to add a second answer to my question, pointing out that the fix doesn't work under certain kinds of autolayout.

Answer (score 17):

**Edit:** Still the same buggy behavior in Xcode 9 GM (9A235)

As of today (Xcode 9 beta 6 9M214v), the image will only be rendered properly (non-blurry) if the UIImageView has at least 3 spacing-related constraints.

eg. spacing to left, spacing to right, spacing to top, and another constraint to define the UIImageView height.

[image]

Note also that disabling autolayout completely will make all the UIImageView render incorrectly.

I filled rdar://34306192 (http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4968083747766272) for this bug.

Comment: 1 year later with iOS 12 and Xcode 10 GM it's still the same. Have now wasted hours finding this issue. Of course Apple is a small garage company with no resources to fix bugs (or at least document them).

Comment: @ernesto please consider duping my radar then, thanks!

Comment: Is there a quick way to dupe it without describing the bug in my own words and also providing a test case?

Comment: @ernesto sure, you can download [Brisk](https://github.com/br1sk/brisk), and use Cmd+Shift+N to file a duplicate by giving my radar id : 34279759

Comment: Any updates on this? Still no solution to make it works without mentioned workarounds?

Comment: @StasIvanov Nope. My radars are closed as duplicates, but the original radars are still marked as "Open". The best you can do to make things go faster is to dupe the radar to make it clear to Apple that they need to fix this.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue multiple times with the new `Preserves Vector Data`.

Super simple solution that worked very well *for me*:

1. **Never** set the `UIImageView` `image` property in Interface Builder, just leave it empty.
2. Set the `image` value programmatically.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow . Thank you so much . Set image name in code is the solution

Comment: Can't believe that's the solution! Thanks!

Comment: This solution still does the trick in 2020, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In my case (*Xcode 9.4.1*), with `imageView` created in Interface Builder - I noticed that when I initially arrive on the screen, the image is blurry. If I then change device orientation, the image becomes crisp. I tried calling different methods manually in `viewDidLoad()` and here is what I found so far:

This worked:

```
let image = imageView.image
imageView.image = nil
imageView.image = image
```

None of these worked:

```
imageView.layoutSubviews()
imageView.layoutMarginsDidChange()
imageView.setNeedsLayout()
imageView.setNeedsDisplay()
imageView.reloadInputViews()
imageView.updateConstraints()
imageView.contentMode = .center ; imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```

You should of course extend or subclass `UIImageView` if you'll be calling it often, like this for example

```
class UIImageViewWithPreserveVectorDataFix: UIImageView {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let image = self.image
        self.image = nil
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

(and then of course set `UIImageViewWithPreserveVectorDataFix` as the class in Interface Builder)

Comment: Excellent research, thanks! I wonder if this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50787278/341994