# UIImageView image does not update visibly when image property is set

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView whose user interaction is true and to which I have given a tap gesture recognizer, whose action handler is as follows:

```
@IBAction func tap(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let iv = sender.view as! UIImageView
    let im = iv.image!
    let im2 = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:im.size).image { _ in
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(origin:.zero, size:im.size)).fill()
    }
    iv.image = im2
}
```

I expect the image displayed, when I tap the image view, to be replaced by a solid red image. This works fine on my High Sierra machine running Xcode 9.4. But on my Sierra MacBook running Xcode 9.2, nothing visibly happens.

It's weird. By pausing in the debugger, I can see that the new image is being constructed correctly:

[image]

The image *is* being replaced, but the image view isn't being redrawn. Adding calls like `setNeedsDisplay` does nothing.

Moreover, if I then proceed to replace the image view's image with a *different* image, I see the *red* image!

```
    iv.image = im2
    delay(0.5) {
        iv.image = im // causes im2 to appear!
    }
```

Some sort of behind-the-scenes caching is evidently causing the image view to get behind in its display by one image.

Can anyone shed light on this? It's presumably a bug in iOS itself, and perhaps in 9.2 specifically; how would one work around it? (Obviously one could substitute another image view wholesale, but that wouldn't tell us what's going on with the caching.)

Comment: I suppose the code runs from a UIViewController. Can't you just add a property and refer the imageView directly with it from within the tap handler? I mean that I won't use sender.view to refer the ImageView.

Comment: This is probably a stretch but perhaps there is some "magic" going on with the `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`. Do you still have this issue if you create the red image using other techniques such as the good old `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`?

Comment: @rmaddy I don't know that it's a stretch at all; I had the same idea. I'll try it...

Comment: @rmaddy No, it doesn't change anything. I think the "magic" must be in the image view itself (maybe combined with the fact that the image is being generated in real time, but then how do we explain the fact that the generated image is visible in the debugger?).

Comment: @lookaji No, changing how the image view is _referred to_ changes nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a workaround:

```
iv.image = im2
delay(0.05) {
    iv.image = nil
    iv.image = im2
}
```

But what a horror... Omitting any of those assignments, or reducing the `delay` to zero (e.g. by calling `DispatchQueue.main.async` instead), causes the workaround to fail.

Comment: Moreover, I haven't _explained_ anything, even though I now have code that "works".

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this problem in Xcode 13. Set the `contentModel` to `center` in the xib file

or

```
iv.contentMode = .center
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this works for me, change the contentMode of the UIImageView to .center